# Trigger callback when slide dragged is over centralised position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider, swiper.js

I cannot find a clear way to use the API to log the slide index that is hovered over the central position. (i.e the slide that will snap to centre when drag is released).

I have built a number line with drag and release functionality, that logs the current slide index on the screen. I have used a combination of the slides lengths and swiper.progress to roughly calculate when a slide is dragged over the middle, but it gets inaccurate when using different sized slides (see GIF)

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiperjs-middle-slide-issue-k2x6jt

[See gif of correct snapping, but incorrect highlighting based on calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U31KT.gif)

Is there anything in the API that will allow me to highlight a slide when it is the chosen slide to snap to the middle?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperClass, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import './TimelineStepper.css';
import { Autoplay } from 'swiper/modules';
import { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper/types';

interface Timestamp {
  label: string;
}

interface TimelineStepperProps {
  onTimelineChange: (index: number, label: string) => void;
}

const generateTimestamps = (): Timestamp[] => {
  const timestamps: Timestamp[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    const label = `${i.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`;
    timestamps.push({ label });
  }

  return timestamps;
};

const TimelineStepper: React.FC<TimelineStepperProps> = ({ onTimelineChange }) => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState<number>(12);
  const [autoplay, setAutoplay] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const timestamps = generateTimestamps();
  const swiperRef = useRef<SwiperClass | null>(null);
  const swiperContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);


  const handleSlideClick = (index: number) => {
    setCurrentSlide(index);
    onTimelineChange(index, timestamps[index].label);
  };

  const handleSlideChange = (swiper: SwiperClass) => {
    setCurrentSlide(swiper.realIndex);
    onTimelineChange(swiper.realIndex, timestamps[swiper.realIndex].label);
  };

  const toggleAutoplay = () => {
    setAutoplay(!autoplay);
  };

  const calculateMiddleSlideIndex = (progress: number): number => {
    const swiper = swiperRef.current;

    if (!swiper) {
      return 0;
    }

    const slidesInfo: [number, number][] = Array.from(swiper.slides).map((slide, index) => [index, slide.offsetWidth]);

    // Calculate the total width of all slides
    const totalWidth = slidesInfo.reduce((acc, [, width]) => acc + width, 0);

    // Calculate the width of the virtual middle section, subtracting half of the first and last slide widths
    const newTotalWidth = totalWidth - slidesInfo[0][1] / 2 - slidesInfo[slidesInfo.length - 1][1] / 2;

    // Calculate the position in the whole slider based on progress using the adjusted total width
    const currentPosition = progress * newTotalWidth;

    let middleSlideIndex = 0;
    let cumulativeWidth = 0;

    // Iterate through slidesInfo to find the one containing the middle position
    for (const [slideIndex, slideWidth] of slidesInfo) {
      const slideStart = cumulativeWidth;
      console.log(slideWidth, slideIndex)
      // const slideStart = cumulativeWidth + slideWidth / 2;

      const slideEnd = slideStart + slideWidth + (slideWidth / 2);

      if (currentPosition >= slideStart && currentPosition <= slideEnd) {
        middleSlideIndex = slideIndex;
      }

      cumulativeWidth += slideWidth;
    }

    // If the current slide is partially over the middle point, set it as the middleSlideIndex
    if (currentPosition > cumulativeWidth) {
      middleSlideIndex += 1;
    }

    onTimelineChange(middleSlideIndex, timestamps[middleSlideIndex]?.label);
    setCurrentSlide(middleSlideIndex);
    return middleSlideIndex;
  };




  const swiperParams: SwiperOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: false,
    navigation: false,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 500,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    modules: [Autoplay],
  };

  if (swiperRef.current) {
    if (autoplay) {
      swiperRef.current.autoplay.start();
    } else {
      swiperRef.current.autoplay.stop();
    }
  }


  return (
    <div ref={swiperContainerRef} className='swiper-main-wrapper'>
      <Swiper
        {...swiperParams}
        onSwiper={(swiper) => {
          swiperRef.current = swiper;
        }}
        onSlideChange={(swiper) => handleSlideChange(swiper)}
        onTouchStart={() => setAutoplay(false)}
        onSliderMove={(swiper) => {
          calculateMiddleSlideIndex(swiper.progress);
        }}
      >
        {timestamps.map((timestamp, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index} onClick={() => handleSlideClick(index)} className={index > 5 ? 'wide-div' : ''}>
            <div>
              <p className='text-label'>{timestamp.label}</p>
              <div className={`container timeline-button ${index === currentSlide ? 'active' : ''} ${index < currentSlide ? 'past' : ''} ${index > currentSlide ? 'upcoming' : ''}`}>
                <div className={`left-line ${index < currentSlide ? 'past-line' : ''}`}></div>
                <div className={`divider ${index < currentSlide ? 'past-divider' : ''}`}></div>
                <div className={`right-line ${index < currentSlide ? 'past-line' : ''}`}></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
      <div className='control-cont'>
        <div className="line"></div>
        <button type="button" onClick={toggleAutoplay}>
          {autoplay ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimelineStepper;
```

I have tried to calculate this using the calculateMiddleSlideIndex function.

Comment: Hey   Could you please create a minimal reproductible example please by using https://codesandbox.io/ for example. That will drastically increase the chance of getting a response.

Comment: Hey sure: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiperjs-middle-slide-issue-k2x6jt